# Storing values in a Matrix during recursion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, shortest-path

I'm currently writing the shortest path algorithm in Matlab. I've written it so that I can calculate its total cost. What I'm trying to do instead is generate a matrix so that I can store values at each element in the shortest path for its current cost. Whenever I try to alter my values I continuously get errors that say that either the matrix is out of bounds or that not all of my output variables have been defined. Here is my working code. How do I alter it so that i can generate a matrix that stores the current cost along all of the elements in the shortest path.

The following code passes in a parameters for the cost matrix and the dimensions and returns the overall cost. The minimumVal is a function I wrote that returns the lowest value from its three parameters.

```
function output = min_path(cost, m, n)

if ((m < 1) || (n < 1))
    output = 9*10000;

elseif ( m == 1)
    output = cost(m,n);

else
    output = cost(m,n) + minimumVal( min_path(cost, m-1, n-1), min_path(cost, m-1, n), min_path(cost, m, n-1) );

end


end % end min_path
```

Comment: What does `minimumVal` do? Why not just use `min`?

Comment: @DaveKielpinski easy one, try `min(1,3,2)`. Else, to OP, "storing values" can be done differently. What I wonder then is: How do you want to store them. Do you mean that you try to do a matrix `output` in which you store the values? In that case I think you need to pass that one with the other inputs and predefine it before the first function call (outside of the function I mean). However, what could else be done could be to store the values in a node tree. This will not give you lot of empty elements. Nested cells can be used for this.

Comment: @patrik Yes, I know. But `min([1,3,2])` works to get the minimum as well. I was wondering if the `minimumVal` function was doing something other than the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one.

```
function output = min_path(cost, m, n, output)

if ((m < 1) || (n < 1))
    output = 9*10000; % Do something here. This well crash

elseif ( m == 1)
    output(m,n) = cost(m,n);

else
    output = cost(m,n) + minimumVal( min_path(cost, m-1, n-1, output),...
               min_path(cost, m-1, n, output), min_path(cost, m, n-1, output) );

end

end % end min_path
```

It is not tested, but it should work. You need to allocate a sufficiently large array to use as primary input. Also, the m=0, n=0 case will crash. Since I am not sure how you want this to be I cannot propose a solution that will not destroy your other code.